# COPY to remote databse from a local file

Tags: postgresql, sqlbulkcopy, soci

There are similar questions but they didn't address my problem:
I have a stored procedure defined in my remote database. As part of it operation, the SP has to bulk insert from a local file (through my application running on my local machine):
the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_realtime(path text, traveltime_table regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN   
    EXECUTE format('COPY temp_table(link_id,start_time,end_time,travel_time,interval_time, travel_mode) FROM %L DELIMITER '';'' CSV', path);
    --...     
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION upsert_realtime(text, regclass)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

the path supplied to the SP is on local machine:

```
select * from upsert_realtime('/home/.../travel_time.txt','realtime_travel_time');
```

Therefore I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'soci::postgresql_soci_error'
  what():  Cannot execute query. ERROR:  could not open file "/home/.../travel_time.txt" for reading: No such file or directory
```

The only thing that comes into my mind is to somehow automatically `scp` the file to the postgresql server and then run the SP, which is not the best idea.
can you help me find a solution? thanks
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [using the wrong path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). This is a common source of errors. It's all about "from the viewpoint of the server."

> COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read
>   from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL
>   user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified
>   from the viewpoint of the server. When PROGRAM is specified, the
>   server executes the given command and reads from the standard output
>   of the program, or writes to the standard input of the program. The
>   command must be specified from the viewpoint of the server, and be
>   executable by the PostgreSQL user. When STDIN or STDOUT is specified,
>   data is transmitted via the connection between the client and the
>   server.

If you don't have a usable path, you need to

- move the file to the server, and use the right path,
- invoke a program on the server that can access your local file,
- use `psql` to connect to the remote server and read the local file.